# Возможно ли использовать переменную для findViewById?

Tags: java, android

К примеру, я хочу создать экземпляр кнопки:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Могу ли я после `R.id.` поставить переменную, в которой будет храниться значение `button`. И как я вообще могу получить экземпляр кнопки `findViewById`, но если у меня будет переменная в которой храниться `id` кнопки.

Comment: попробуйте объяснить подробнее, что именно вы хотите в итоге получить, привидите пример. Дело в том, что R.id.button сама по себе переменная, которая хранит число - уникальный идентификатор кнопки. это число константа для каждого виджета и не может менять свое значение в проекте. Какую еще переменную вы хотите создать и для каких целей?

Comment: Я уже всё понял, спасибо. Я не знал, что R.id.button является переменной сама по себе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int btnID= R.id.button;

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(btnID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделать это можно следующим способом:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("button", "id", getPackageName());
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(resId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val textViewText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewText)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]